# Print Laravel Specific data (Picture) from Database

Tags: database, laravel, printing

I'm using a DOMPDF wrapper for Laravel. I can print an image using this code:

```
public function print1()
    {
            $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
            $pdf->loadHTML('<img style="width:800px;height:1000px;" src="pic/m_cert.png">');
            return $pdf->download('medcert.pdf');
    }
```

And now, I'm trying to print image from my database.

```
public function print_img($id)
{
            $bprint = UserInfo::find($id);
          $pdf = PDF::loadView("<img src='upload/userpics/'.$bprint->user_info_img>");
            return $pdf->download('Picture.pdf');
}
```

This is my routes and the button from my blade

```
Route::get('/print_img/{id}','PDF_Controller@print_img')->name('print_img');
```

This is my button

```
<a class="btn" href="{{ route('print_img',$user->user_info_id_number) }}">
                  Print
            </a>
```

and I'm getting

```
Trying to get property 'user_info_img' of non-object
```

I checked my database and the name is correct. I also input my model use\UserInfo;

Second thing, how am I gonna input the name of user in the

```
 return $pdf->download('user_img'.$user->user_info_id_number.'.pdf');
```

Is this gonna work?

Answer (score 1):

`UserInfo::find($id);` acts upon the primary key, if you have set your primary key in your model to something other than id by doing:

otherwise you can set other key in model

```
protected  $primaryKey = 'slug';
```

then find will search by that key instead.

Laravel also expects the id to be an integer, if you are using something other than an integer (such as a string) you need to set the incrementing property on your model to false:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: ohh yeah ! I forgot ! thanks a lot man.. 
I got another error..
View [<img src=asset('upload.userpics'. 1582210888.jpg)>] not found.

I checked the path and Image file name is correct